# Cannot set profile image in Visual Studio Team Services team project

Tags: tfs, settings, azure-devops

I created a VS Team Services team project and click on settings in the upper right corner. I am admin of the collection and the project. In the "Overview" page I click on the default image and the dialog "Profile Image" appears. I click on the file-selection-button and select a PNG from my desktop (80x80, 3 KB).

When I hit OK, the preview image is working for a second and then shows the default image again. When I hit Save Changes, nothing changes.

Comment: I have a similar issue. When you open the console (F12) in either IE or Chrome you will notice that this is because of CORS:
SEC7120: Origin https://acme.visualstudio.com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: I've been noticing this for a while and I'm kinda curious if it's just an incomplete feature.  I would love to have my individual icons in VSO to represent my different projects, but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm admin on two different VSO sites (under two logins for two businesses) and I first noticed this about 2 months ago.  Today I tried again on my other VSO site and had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed some days ago

Comment: Could you please provide some reference on what the bug was and in what version it was fixed? A link to some release notes would suffice.

Comment: The bug was that in Visual Studio Online changing either the Project Profile image or a Team image had no effect. Visual Studio Online is a hosted product by Microsoft that doesn't have "versions". Microsoft releases a new sprint about 3 weeks. I don't remember to see the fix in any post of the TFS team, I tested each "release" and at July the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to fix this one in chrome by hitting Ctrl + F5 (Which refreshes the cache in Google Chrome) on the page/screen that still displayed the older version of my profile picture in VSTS.